# How long is the condition expression of the if-statement when I have to get it out of the parentheses?

Tags: c#

I'm talking about the XXX of the following

```
if(XXX)
{
}
```

if the condition expression was too long, I think I have to do like the following

```
bool IsOK = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
if(IsOK)
{
}
```

Or I have to make it a method.

Comment: bool IsOk is just true or false, why XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX this is not a long text. "If" is just to evaluate or compare and will be better if you use variables for better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't HAVE to, but you can do it for readability. The condition can either go inside the if, or be stored in a variable and evaluated, then that variable can go in the if. Either way, it's essentially the same thing, but in using the variable, you make the code slightly more readable.

Comment: +1. "make the code slightly more readable" as in "have chance to make code readable when give reasonable name to variable." IsOK is not ok. :)